# Problem with $0! = 1$

Tags: factorial

Okay, we know that

$$4!=4 \cdot 3\cdot 2 \cdot 1=24$$   $$5!=5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=120$$
$$6!=6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=720$$

This is can be written as

$$n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$$

We obtain

$$6! = \frac {7!}{7} = 720$$
$$5! = \frac {6!}{6} = 120$$
$$4! = \frac {5!}{5} = 24$$

If we take $0! = 1$

$$0! = \frac {1!}{1} = \frac {1}{0}$$

Using other way

$$0!=0\cdot0 = 0$$

Why is $0!$ equal to $1$?

Comment: Why $\frac{1!}{1!}=\frac{1}{0}$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Sorry for that.

Comment: And literally 30 other questions... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20969

Comment: After spotting your mistake (see Michael), you will conclude $0!=1$.

Comment: Where you have $\dfrac{7!}{7!},$ you need $\dfrac{7!} 7.$ And $\dfrac{1!} 1$ is not $\dfrac 1 0, $ but $\dfrac 1 1,$ so that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It so that the equality $n!=n\times(n-1)!$ holds for every natural number.

Comment: Natural numbers do or don't include $0$ depending on the author.

Comment: For me,they don't, but that doesn't invalidate what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The core idea of factorial is arranging n numbers so by definition 0 can be arranged in one set only as empty set can be arranged in one way so 0!=1